# How to use Jinja2 loop index in Ansible hostvars?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to get IP address from inventory using Jinja2 loop index inside hostvars (from Ansible):

Inventory is like:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.1
    host2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.2
    host3:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.3
    service_nodes:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:
        host3:
```

**`template.yml`** is like:

```yaml
...
{% for host in service_nodes %}
  - {{ loop.index }}:{{ hostvars[groups.service_nodes[{{ loop.index }}]].ansible_host }}
...
{% endfor %}
...
```

I ran the playbook but encountered:

```json
{"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'.
```

And I've checked on [AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437561/ansibleerror-template-error-while-templating-string-expected-token-end-of-sta) but seems it's not my answer.

Also, I tried these on the template but failed:

```yaml
{% set idx = loop.index %}
  - {{ loop.index }}:{{ hostvars[groups.service_nodes[{{ idx }}]].ansible_host }}
```

and

```yaml
  - {{ loop.index }}:{{ hostvars[groups.service_nodes["{{ loop.index }}"]].ansible_host }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the directive *`children`* to declare  the [group of hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups) *`service_nodes`*

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.1
    host2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.2
    host3:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.3
  children:
    service_nodes:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:
        host3:
```

Test it. See the output of the command

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    service_nodes:
      hosts:
        host1:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.1
        host2:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.2
        host3:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.3
    ungrouped: {}
```

Then the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: hosts.yml.j2
        dest: /tmp/hosts.yml
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

and the template

```yaml
shell> cat hosts.yml.j2
{% for host in groups.service_nodes %}
  - {{ loop.index }}:{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_host'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

give

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/hosts.yml
  - 1:192.168.1.1
  - 2:192.168.1.2
  - 3:192.168.1.3
```